# Probability equivalence of sum of card drawn from a deck

Tags: probability, card-games

Two people draw 5 cards each from a well-shuffled pack of cards. What is the probability that the sum of numeric values of the two people is the same?
Ace is 1, King is 13, Queen is 12 and Jack is 11.

I tried a few approaches, but I wasn't able to find anything concrete to find a solution.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Seems messy, as the sums aren't independent.  I suggest sampling it to get a sense of the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Math.ME. Please describe in your post your attempts at solving your problem.

Comment: I was thinking about the problem last night. However, I wasn't able to think of a method to solve it.

Comment: First step: get the distribution of sums for five cards.

Comment: What if you start with easier steps. Step 1: $1$ card; step 2: $2$ cards, ...